# Firebase message exporting

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm new to Firebase and I have a project that I'm working on, currently, there are many sent messages that I want to compare to each other, but I could not find any way to export them.
What I need to export is these data [see attached 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaFcQ.png), I want similar to this [attached 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lbqxa.png)

I tried using the report page but I can't export it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the Firebase Cloud Messaging console has a feature to export the data. You can either just copy/paste it from the UI and do the necessary cleanup manually, or you can configure [export of the underlying detailed data to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android#bigquery-data-export) and reconstructs the aggregates from there.